# Wordpress site_url repeated twice on live server

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this php code form my Wordpress site, I works as expected on my localhost, but not when I moved it to live:

```
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">
        <?php echo $menu_item->title  ?>
            </a>
        </li>
```

On my localhost the url produced from the the code above looks like this: 
http://localhost/wordpress/#home

But when moving to live, the exact same php code produces this url:
http://www.example.com/wordpress/#http://www.example.com/wordpress/#home

My site url field in wp_options table looks like this:
http://www.example.com/wordpress/

Why is the URL repeated twice when the site is live?

Comment: in the wp_options table the rows for site_url and home need to have http:// in front of them.  have you check it is there or not ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it again! http:// is in front of both site_url and home!

Comment: you can try with home_url() may be it helps you

Comment: I have tried, same result! It is only appending, not replacing!

Comment: have you created any custom function in your functions.php file ?

Comment: What does the entire anchor look like? <a href="... etc

Comment: I'll kind of figured it out. I seems to be a jQuery issue, I had to change jQuery from version 3.1.1 to 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Check your `wp-config.php` weather `WP_SITEURL` is defined or not, if not then there is workaround to fix this issue by defining `WP_SITEURL` constant in `wp-config.php` like `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com/wordpress/');`

Comment: Thank you answering, but the url is still repeated twice after adding your suggestion to wp-config.php!

Comment: Then you need to check for wordpress hooks which you have defined on site_url or home_url.